# Restore PostgreSQL database using java

Tags: java, postgresql, runtime.exec

im using the following code to Restore PostgreSQL database using java

```
 Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
 Process p;
 String cmd ="D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_restore.exe --host localhost --port 5432 --username postgres --dbname mytestqq --role postgres --no-password  --verbose D:\sathish\rawDatabase.backup";
 p = r.exec(cmd);
```

i have 42 tables in the rawDatabase.backup file but only one table is getting restored why the rest of the tables are not happening whats wrong in my code?
thanks in advance!!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I got the solution

```
Runtime r = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process p;
ProcessBuilder pb;
r = Runtime.getRuntime();
pb = new ProcessBuilder( 
    "D:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.1\\bin\\pg_restore.exe",
    "--host=localhost",
    "--port=5432",
    "--username=postgres",
    "--dbname=mytestqq",
    "--role=postgres",
    "--no-password",
    "--verbose",
   "D:\\sathish\\rawDatabase.backup");
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
p = pb.start();
InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String ll;
while ((ll = br.readLine()) != null) {
 System.out.println(ll);
}
```

Comment: @Craig finally i got the solution

Comment: Thanks for following up. The code you show looks almost right, you just need to wait for the process to complete and get the return value to make sure the restore actually succeeded.

Comment: @Sathish, you gave a wrong answer. According to [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html) long variants of parameters (started with 2 dashes, e.g. "--host") should looks like this: --param_name=param_value. In your case "--host=localhost" and so on.

Answer (score 7):

It's surprising that the command you show works at all, since you're failing to quote the spaces in the command path. Try:

```
String[] cmd = {
    "D:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.1\\bin\\pg_restore.exe",
    "--host", "localhost",
    "--port", "5432",
    "--username", "postgres",
    "--dbname", "mytestqq",
    "--role", "postgres",
    "--no-password",
    "--verbose",
    "D:\\sathish\\rawDatabase.backup"
};
p = r.exec(cmd);
```

Changes:

- Convert the single-string form to the much safer arguments array form of the `exec` call;
- Double the backslashes in the `rawDatabase` path since your original command fails to escape backslashes, so `\r` is a carriage return in the string instead of the `\` char followed by the `r` char.
- Switch to doubled backslashes instead of forward slashes on the program path for consistency. This change probably doesn't matter.

Also check the return status of the process. You must use [`Process.waitFor()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) then once it has exited use [`Process.exitValue()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29) to determine the result. You should examine the stderr and stdout captured by the `Process` object for errors and logging information.

The reason your program continues not to work is probably because:

- You have old `pg_restore` processes hanging around holding locks; and/or
- You aren't consuming stdout and stderr so `pg_restore` runs out of buffered pipe space and blocks writing on the output stream.

This will all be much simpler if you [use `ProcessBuilder` instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#start%28%29). ProcessBuilder lets you provide file streams to write output to and generally takes care of a lot of this for you. You must still wait for the process to terminate and check its return code though.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i have tried your code but still facing the same issue...so strange

Comment: @Sathish Did you also follow my advice to wait for the `pg_restore` process to finish with `Process.waitFor` and check for a non-zero return code from `Process.exitValue`? Also, I just updated the answer, I hadn't noticed that you also failed to double backslashes in your command.

Comment: ya i have given all the instructions double backslashes p.waitFor()and p.exitValue() still facing same issue

Comment: @Sathish OK, and what does `p.exitValue()` return? If you read and print the error stream from [`getErrorStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream()) is there anything informative there?

Comment: @Sathish "keep on loading" ... that means nothing. Please be clear and explicit. Do you mean "the program doesn't exit, it stays at `p.waitFor()`" ? If so, that's because the `pg_restore` process is still running. Updating answer with a few hints.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27330/discussion-between-sathish-and-craig-ringer)

Comment: @Sathish -> chat please, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27330/discussion-between-sathish-and-craig-ringer . I will not respond further on this comment thread, so use chat.

Answer (score 0):

The following code perfectly work in taking the postgres DB dump using JAVA code..Try this

```
List<String> cmds = new ArrayList<String>();
         cmds.add("C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.1\\bin\\pg_dump.exe");
         cmds.add("-i");
         cmds.add("-h");
         cmds.add("localhost");
         cmds.add("-p");
         cmds.add("5432");
         cmds.add("-U");
         cmds.add("YOUR PG USERNAME");
         cmds.add("-F");
         cmds.add("c");
         cmds.add("-b");
         cmds.add("-v");
         cmds.add("-f");
         cmds.add("\"E:\\pg_dump.backup\"");//Location to store db Dump backup
         cmds.add("lmd");
         ProcessBuilder process = new ProcessBuilder();
         process.command(cmds).start();
```