# how to create backup of postgres database using java

Tags: java, postgresql

i want to take backup of postgres database using java. I am using following code for this
but this is not working and not generating dump.

```
String pgDump = "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.2\\bin\\pg_dump";
          String dumpFile = "D:\\test\\"+ tenant.getTenantAsTemplate()+".sql";
          String sql = pgDump+" -h localhost -U postgres -P postgres " + tenant.getTenantAsTemplate()+" > "+dumpFile;
          Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(sql);
          int time = p.waitFor();
          System.out.println("time is "+time);
          if(time == 0){
            System.out.println("backup is created");
          }
          else{
            System.out.println("fail to create backup");
          }
```

Here i am getting time is 1.

This is also **operating system** dependent and we need also **pg_dump**. is there any other way to generate backup of database without pg_dump?

please reply soon.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743529/restore-postgresql-database-using-java has a nice example of what you want and can be easily adjusted to your dump command.

Comment: Use cron + script. Don't use java - it's the wrong tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to generate a database backup without `pg_dump`, using the regular SQL connection. It's a bit of an FAQ, but the people who want the feature never step up to do the work to implement the feature in PostgreSQL.

I guess technically you could use a replication connection to do a physical base backup like `pg_basebackup` does, but that's not really what you want, requires copying all databases on the machine, and would be a lot of work.

You should use the `String[]` form of `Runtime.exec` as [I mentioned in a related answer regarding `pg_restore`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15743529/restore-postgresql-database-using-java).

You must also check the process [exit value](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()) to see if it terminated successfully or not, and you must be careful to handle, not just swallow, any exceptions thrown.

Your code fails to check the exit value, and I think it's probably generating a malformed command that's failing with a non-zero exit code, probably because you are not correctly quoting the path to `pg_dump`. To see what's wrong, print the final assembled command line, you'll see something like:

```
C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.2\bin\pg_dump -h localhost ....
```

which cmd.exe will split into:

```
c:\Program
Files\postgresql\9.2\bin\pg_dump
-h
localhost
```

... etc

See the problem?

Do *not* just quote the path to `pg_dump` to work around this. Use the `String[]` form of `exec` and you won't have to, plus it'll work correctly for other things like accidental `%environmentvars%`  in paths.

Comment: Thanx for your reply. But i tried with this string array also but doesn't work and exit value again giving 1. I also tried with **ProcessBuilder** also but it also not working.

Comment: @kamal OK, so it's exiting with an error. Have a look at the command's stdout/stderr output to see why.

Comment: thanx for your reply. Actually this is not giving any error and which procedure you told me of String [], i tried with that but with string array i m not able to create dump of database but i can restore  database with that successfully. To create backup and restore procedures are different or same. sorry i m asking lot of questions.

Comment: @kamal You must look at the stdout / stderr, to see what the command's error message is. You will find this a lot easier if you use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).

Comment: it's asking me for password (9.5 postgres) -P is not working

Comment: @Cybermonk I have no idea what the context here is. Post a new question. If this post is relevant to your question, put a link to it in your question.